# AutoBean, Arrays/Lists properties and JSNI

Tags: java, gwt, jsni, autobean

I am somehow struggling with Arrays and JSNI in the context of Autobeans.
In one of my GWT projects I retrieve a data from backend using JSON.
Once the data is retrieved on the client I want to visualize it using a custom visualization widgets (developed in javascript).

Here are the components:

**JSON structure**:

```
{'ids':[1,2,3,4],'data':[[1.0],[1.0,2.0],[1.0,2.0,3.0] ... ]}
```

Basically I have two datasets in my json payload. **ids** is a array of ints (`int[]`) and **data** is a array of arrays of floats (`float[][]`)

There are of course different ways to parse the data on the client. I decided to use AutoBeans. So I defined an interface for my json structure.

**AutoBean**:

```
interface MyData {
   List<Integer> ids;
   List<List<Float>> data;
}
```

Parsing the data works fine.

My custom visualization widgets has a API function to set the data that looks like this:

```
function api_setData(ids,data) {
   //ids should be an Array of Ints
   //data should be an array of array of Floats.
}
```

The problem is that with JSNI I can't use normal Java arrays. I have to use `JsArray`.

```
public final native void setData(JsArrayInteger ids,JsArray<JsArrayInteger> data /*-{
       this.api_setData(ids,data);
    }-*/;
```

So I have to convert my AutoBean properties (**data** and **ids**) to JsArray instances. 
Is there a better/nicer way to do that?

Or maybe I should use `JSONParser` instead of `AutoBeans`
Is that more efficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have to deal with JSNI, moreover if you're using your `MyData` interface only on the client-side, then don't use AutoBeans. Use JSON overlays instead:

```java
public class MyData extends JavaScriptObject {
   protected MyData() { /* required for JSOs */ }

   public final native JsArrayInteger getIds() /*-{ return this.ids; }-*/;

   public final native JsArray<JsArrayNumber> getData() /*-{ return this.data; }-*/;
}
```

And then to parse your JSON:

```java
MyData data = JsonUtils.safeEval(jsonStr);
customVisualizationWidget.setData(data.getIds(), data.getData());
```

---

Alternately, assuming you only need you parsed data for setData, then simply use `JavaScriptObject`.

In your widget:

```java
public final native void setData(JavaScriptObject obj) /*-{
   this.api_setData(obj.ids, obj.data);
}-*/;
```

When you need to parse the JSON and give it to the widget:

```java
customVisualizationWidget.setData(JsonUtils.safeParse(jsonStr));
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas for the feedback. 
I was suspecting that AutoBean might not be the best fit for my use case. I guess from a performance point of view JSO and AutoBean should be equally fast (My data array might have 200k float values).

Comment: JSOs will always perform better than AutoBeans, because AutoBeans has wrappers around JSOs. They are very think wrappers though, and are only instantiated as needed, so it should generally not be an issue; but still.